# ubuntu servers - what do i need to do to keep it uptodate

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am setting up an ubuntu server and want to know what I should be doing on it regularly.

`apt-get update/upgrade` seems obvious.

Is there a glsa check for example?  Anything else I should be running?  I guess it depends on what is installed, but I am thinking of the core system for now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Upgrading packages as you mentioned is the most important thing. A couple of tools that can make that easier:

- cron-apt, to notify you by email when there are upgrades to install; and
- unattended-upgrades, to automatically apply non-interactive upgrades

Ubuntu also has a [security announcement list](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn), but in my experience it is really just a duplicate of the package upgrades that cron-apt will notify you about. On the other hand it will provide a bit more information on what is being fixed (or what is vulnerable) in each security upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I installed munin on my servers so that I can monitor all sorts of things about them, including whether apt thinks there are packages to install.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just do the updates create a text file with:

```
apt-get -yq update
apt-get -yq upgrade
```

and add it to crontab for whatever timeline you want.

Comment: Doing this will also likely clobber any configuration file changes you may have made

Comment: Although I suppose that could be a problem in some cases  I have yet to experience it myself  i have 4 Local Debian servers and 4 Remote (Datacenter servers) ones also running Debian and I've been using debian as my only server OS for a few years.

Comment: Forcing "yes" (-y) is awfully dangerous.

Comment: I "could" be but as I said above this has yet to fail me.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get moo
```

try it :)

Answer (score -3):

I put the following line in /etc/crontab

```
2 */2 * * * root    apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y --force-yes upgrade && apt-get -qq clean
```

Beware that it does not install new packages, therefore it might miss some kernel updates: you still have to run synaptic/aptitude once in a while.